# How I can open admin page in other tab with redirect:to?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

How I can open admin page in other tab (target blank) when user login?

In my controller after validate return this:

```
return Redirect::to('/adminpanel');
```

Comment: Is it Laravel 4 or Laravel 5?

Answer (score 1):

it is bad solution, but may help a little bit. 
`echo " <script>window.open(".Redirect::to('/adminpanel').")</script>";` I did not test it out, so dont quarantee it works. Browser may block popup when do it this way.

Another way is to redirect to some view where is placed javascript code like

```
if({{$url}}){
    $(document).ready(function(){
          window.open({{$url}}, "_blank"); 
      });
}
```

and from backend

```
return Redirect::to('/adminpanel')->with(compact('url'));
```

Comment: That's actually a more javascript solution, not a Laravel one. And yes, opening tabs without user interaction will cause browser to block the popup.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't redirect user from backend to new tab. Just use any Javascript solution or even AJAX request with `.done` (jQuery like) callback which will redirect user after request finished.